# React - How to prevent lag during logic-based component change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, frontend, styled-components

This is my code:

```
export const StyledCard = (props: CardProps) => {
    const [loaded, setLoaded] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
    
    return (
        <StyledContainer>
            {<StyledImage onLoad={() => setLoaded(true)} src={props.imageURL} alt=""/>}
            {!customImageLoaded && <ComponentWhichIsNotAnImageAndCannotBeUsedAsFallbackSource />}
        </StyledContainer>
    )
}
```

I have a state so that a placeholder component renders when the image hasn't loaded. However, when the image finally loads, there's a short moment when BOTH (the image and the placeholder component) are rendered and this makes the container double the height before eventually removing the placeholder component.

Is there a way to prevent this short double render?

If I make the condition `{loaded && <img onLoad={() => setLoaded(true)} src={props.imageURL} alt=""/>}`, only the placeholder renders and the img never loads because `onLoad` can never trigger `loaded` to false.

Also note: the placeholder component isn't an image so I can't use a fallback source.

Is there anyway to optimize this and prevent the double render / lag issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you can hide the image using styles. In this case the image will be loaded, and after that you will remove the hidden properties.

```
export const StyledCard = (props: CardProps) => {
    const [loaded, setLoaded] = React.useState<boolean>(false);

    
    return (
        <StyledContainer>
            {<StyledImage 
               style={{display: loaded ? 'block' : 'none'}} 
               onLoad={() => setLoaded(true)} src={props.imageURL} alt=""
            />}
            {!loaded && <ComponentWhichIsNotAnImageAndCannotBeUsedAsFallbackSource />}
        </StyledContainer>
    )
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! this worked! don't know why I didn't think of this lol